# Compare only DATE in a DATETIME field from ASP.NET code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table stored in SQL Server database. One of the fields of the table is of type `DATETIME`. I also have a ASP `Calendar` whose date is compared with the `DATETIME` filed of Database.

The problem is I don't want to compare the time. Only dates has to be compared. What is the SQL query for doing so.

This is what I used:

```
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("
SELECT AUDIT.AUDIT_DETAILS, USERS.USER_NAME, AUDIT.DATE_TIME, IP  
FROM USERS JOIN AUDIT ON (USERS.USER_ID = AUDIT.USER_ID) 
WHERE USERS.USERS_NAME LIKE '%"+TextBox1.Text+"%' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),AUDIT.DATE_TIME,110) like "+Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date+"'%'", conn);
```

I'm getting correct output in the SQL Server explorer but when run from browser through asp.net the query result is empty

Comment: Can you please show in which format you are testing in SQL Server explorer and in which format is your Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date? Maybe the problem is date format.

Comment: I too think so. I have actually not specified any format. How do i make them both in same format.

Comment: You can put Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date in what format SQL needs like this Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString("format") where instead of format you must write format that you need like dd/MM/yyyy or yyyy/MM/dd

Comment: I too think that s the problem. Can you post a sample.

Comment: Give it a try, I can't give a simple without seeing code.

Comment: This worked: `SELECT AUDIT.AUDIT_DETAILS, USERS.USERS_NAME, AUDIT.DATE_TIME, IP  FROM USERS JOIN AUDIT ON (USERS.USER_ID=AUDIT.USER_ID) WHERE USERS.USERS_NAME LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),AUDIT.DATE_TIME,105) LIKE '%" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("d-MM-yyyy")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get only date from Datetime in SQL like this

```
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

And after that you can compare to that value.

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying your query as below

```
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT AUDIT.AUDIT_DETAILS, USERS.USER_NAME, AUDIT.DATE_TIME, IP  
  FROM USERS JOIN AUDIT ON (USERS.USER_ID = AUDIT.USER_ID) 
  WHERE USERS.USERS_NAME LIKE '%"+TextBox1.Text+"%' AND
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),AUDIT.DATE_TIME,106) ==    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST('"+Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date+"' as DATETIME),106)", conn);
```